# New coder-- frstrated in recreating Photoshop image

Tags: html, email, digital-signature

I'm trying to setup a new email signature for Apple mail using Adobe Photoshop--> Dreamweaver

Please find attached:

1. [the way I WANT my signature to look (the gridded one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teFnD.jpg)
2. [the way my signature currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5XS.jpg)

I've been working on this for 6 hours. I can't get:

1. the social media buttons to align directly under the left border of the square part of the logo
2. the phone numbers and social media buttons to exist on the same plane on the bottom

Here is my code as it currently stands:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>BPM Email Signature</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/lj4nfr0cj/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_03.jpg" />
      </td>
    <td><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/ia40eige7/bpmcontact_info_17.jpg" width="150" /><td><table width="600" border="0">  <tbody  <td> <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/hdyc7kry7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_07.jpg""/> <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/ng5yy2ge7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_09.jpg"/> <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/kncre1g1r/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_11.jpg"/> <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/fsj2frhq7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_13.jpg"/> <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/jfytltpxb/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_15.jpg"/></td>
```

Comment: Also need to hyperlinks to 6 images (5 buttons and logo for website) and have NO idea how :( I've been watching YouTube videos since 10am and nothing is clear enough, or it's all on a PC (I'm on a MacBook air).

Comment: does your apple mail signature allow css styles?

Comment: I have no idea. . . All of the forums I was reading and the videos I watched this morning said to use HTML!

Comment: Jenna, you're nearly there. I suggest that you cut the top row image in two so that BPM Bill Pollack is in one image and the blu box and the work Music is in another.  From there it's an easy fix which anyone here can walk you through. I have set up a code pen for you here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWeyXa?editors=1010

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWeyXa?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>BPM Email Signature</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/lj4nfr0cj/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_03.jpg" /></a>
      </td>
    <td><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/ia40eige7/bpmcontact_info_17.jpg" style="width: 150px; margin-left:-5px; margin-right: 45px; margin-top: 15px;" /><td>
    <table width="600" border="0">  
    <td> 
<a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/hdyc7kry7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_07.jpg"/></a>
<a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/ng5yy2ge7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_09.jpg"/></a>
<a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/kncre1g1r/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_11.jpg"/></a>
<a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/fsj2frhq7/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_13.jpg"/></a> 
<a href="###" target="_blank"><img src="http://s19.postimg.org/jfytltpxb/BPM_Email_Siganture_1_15.jpg"/></a>
    </td>
</html>
```

Where you see the "**###**" in the...

```
<a href="###" target="blank">
```

replace with the appropriate link. :)

Comment: OH MY GOD you guys are incredible! Thank you so much!! Seriously, I can't thank you enough. Wow, me and my wedding signer father are so grateful to you all + this community.

Is there a also a way to ensure that the bottom aligns? The bottom line of 'cell' and the social media buttons aren't quite matched!

Comment: http://s19.postimg.org/kxkqgrblv/Screen_Shot_2016_03_20_at_8_55_38_PM.jpg    <<hugs>>

Comment: I can probably just replace the 'contact info' image with revised one that is tighter on the bottom?

Comment: Lol, you're very welcome! Sorry I didn't catch that. I've updated the code to align the bottom phone # and the social buttons.

Comment: Nick you're my favorite person for the rest of the day ;) 
THANK YOU SO MUCH! xx